# Manage In-App-Purchase after Deprecated UDID method from Apple

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, in-app-purchase, udid

I am using UDID in my previous build to manage In-App-Purchase from my server (To manage credits). Now apple Deprecated UDID methods. So now how I manage this with previous/old users that already purchased the credit/ already have balance in account.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why are you using the UDID? Are you limiting the IAP to a single device?

Comment: In the previous build using UDID to manage credit. And yes its a limited to single device too.

Comment: You're not allowed to limit to a single device according to Apple's rules. It should work on all devices tied to that Apple ID.